# Angular Testing provider useValue for environment throws NullInjectionError

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection, jasmine, angular-test

I have a provider for environment in our Angular application and we have it like this:

`{ provide: 'environment', useValue: environment }`

Alongside this we have a lot of other providers as services as well. Now this works fine in the application but when I run `ng test` it throws an error for any service that uses it.

`NullInjectorError: No provider for environment`

`@Inject('environment') environment: Environment`

How do I progress on this since I need the environment to be injected automatically as well.

Comment: Did you try to import it as well ? `TestBed.configureTestingModule({providers: [environment]});`

Comment: Yes. But I have already added it in the `app.module.ts` as a provider. Other providers are also injected automatically and work. Since I am doing the useValue is it becuase of this or how does this work? Thanks

Comment: In the tests, you should reimport everything. The TestBed don't consider the `app.module.ts` in order to be really isolated.

Comment: Can we add a provider to be available globally in all files rather than adding it. Kind of makes it repetitive.

Comment: You can put the global provider import array into a export variable which you can use inside your app.module as well as in your test bed module

Comment: One question I still had. If we don't add the provider in the configureTestingModule of TestBed, it used the original one. It should also do it for the environment provider as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a new file testing.module.ts in your project:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

@NgModule({
  providers: [
    { provide: 'environment', useValue: environment }
  ]
})
export class TestingModule { }
```

2. Import TestingModule in your test files:

```
import { TestingModule } from './testing.module';

describe('MyService', () => {
  beforeEach(() => TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [ TestingModule ],
    // other configuration
  }));

  it('should be created', () => {
    const service: MyService = TestBed.get(MyService);
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Comment: This makes sense. But I am trying to understand as to why it's not taking the value from the app.module.ts? Since other providers are being injected and I don't need to provide them explicitly. Its only with the environment.

Comment: The issue with your current provider for the environment is that it is only available in the application's root injector, and not in the test's injector. To make the environment available in your tests, you need to provide it in the test setup as well.